# SQL: Summarize Date Data by blocks of Time

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a data set of information that logs events as they happen; and I would like to be able to summarize that data over different time periods during the day.
My RAW data is simply time stamped with the system time of the event.
I have an SQL query that can calculate how many events happen in an hour period.

Example or RAW data over three days,

```
Time_Period             Count
------------------------------  
29/07/13 08:00:00       2  
29/07/13 09:00:00       19  
29/07/13 10:00:00       21  
29/07/13 11:00:00       30  
29/07/13 12:00:00       21  
29/07/13 13:00:00       24  
29/07/13 14:00:00       18  
29/07/13 15:00:00       35  
29/07/13 16:00:00       17  
29/07/13 17:00:00       3  
30/07/13 09:00:00       20  
30/07/13 10:00:00       47  
30/07/13 11:00:00       22  
30/07/13 12:00:00       19  
30/07/13 13:00:00       26  
30/07/13 14:00:00       30  
30/07/13 15:00:00       20  
30/07/13 16:00:00       26  
30/07/13 17:00:00       10  
30/07/13 18:00:00       1  
31/07/13 08:00:00       1  
31/07/13 09:00:00       23  
31/07/13 10:00:00       28  
31/07/13 11:00:00       18  
31/07/13 12:00:00       25  
31/07/13 13:00:00       17  
31/07/13 14:00:00       17  
31/07/13 15:00:00       36  
31/07/13 16:00:00       22  
31/07/13 17:00:00       8  
31/07/13 20:00:00       1
```

However what I would like to achieve is to get this data and get it summarized ignoring the Date part of the field (Not time, like everyone else wants)

I would have a result that looks like this. (For the 3 days above)

```
Time_Period   Sum_Count
-----------------------
08:00:00        23  
09:00:00        89  
10:00:00        71  
11:00:00        67  
12:00:00        72  
13:00:00        71  
14:00:00        55  
15:00:00        97    
16:00:00        49    
17:00:00        12    
18:00:00        1
```

I could do it in code and dump the answer back to a temporary table; however doing it correctly in SQL to begin with would make it easier to call from different systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    HourMinuteSecond=CONVERT(TIME,YOURDATE),
    GroupCount=COUNT(*)
FROM 
   YOURTABLE
GROUP BY CONVERT(TIME,YOURDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as :

```
select count(*),
convert(sysname,DATEPART(HOUR,Time_Period ))+':'+
convert(sysname,DATEPART(minute,Time_Period ))+':'+
convert(sysname,datepart(second,Time_Period ))
from YourTable
group by 
convert(sysname,DATEPART(HOUR,Time_Period ))+':'+
convert(sysname,DATEPART(minute,Time_Period ))+':'+
convert(sysname,datepart(second,Time_Period ))
```

If you use SQL2012, you can build strong typed time using **TIMEFROMPARTS** function. If you use earlier versions, justify strings in example above and add **ORDER BY** clause